# Merge list of dictionaries based on first element but add only one index in dictionary value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following list of dictionaries:

```
[{'person_id': '10114', 'detail_info': [1286, 1]}, {'person_id': '10114', 'detail_info': [1286, 1]}, {'person_id': '10114', 'detail_info': [1286, 3]}]
```

I need this result:

```
[{'person_id': '10114', 'detail_info': [1286, 5]}]
```

I need to add the second element of each `detail_info` when merging.

Comment: Is your data really a string?

Comment: @mozway, no, sorry. Fixed. But `person_id` is a string.

Comment: and is the key to merge '10114' or 1286?

Comment: Is the first element of `"detail_info"` always the same for the same `"person_id"`?

Comment: @user2390182, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to merge on 'person_id' (if not, you can easily change the key):

```
out = {}
for d in l:
    key = d['person_id']
    if not key in out:
        out[key] = d
    else:
        out[key]['detail_info'][1] += d['detail_info'][1]
out = list(out.values())
```

output:

```
[{'person_id': '10114', 'detail_info': [1286, 5]}]
```

input:

```
l = [{'person_id': '10114', 'detail_info': [1286, 1]},
     {'person_id': '10114', 'detail_info': [1286, 1]},
     {'person_id': '10114', 'detail_info': [1286, 3]}]
```